How to write and read back a field of list in Pandas to Excel?
Consider the following dataframe:
dt = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
dt['B']=[[]]
dt=dt.append({'A':2, 'B':[1,2,3]}, ignore_index=True)

dt now has a list of integers in the second row, column B:
    A   B
0   NaN []
1   2   [1, 2, 3] 

I'd like to write dt to an excel file and then read it back:
dt.to_excel('dt.xls')
dt_read = pd.read_excel('dt.xls')

However, upon reading back, the list field is handled as a string:
 dt_read.iloc[1]['B']

is
 u'[1, 2, 3]'

Is there a way to tell Pandas to read it back consistently, as an actual list? Or the only way around is to parse the string?
